# Is there any public Ethereum communication forums or Slack?

Tags: dapp-development

A lot of open source and blockchain projects are using Slack for communication and keeping communities together. Is there any public slack for Ethereum specifically (not DApps)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT 2022:

- [Ethereum R&D Discord](https://discord.gg/VmG7Uxc) ([Source](https://blog.ethereum.org/2020/03/31/eth2-quick-update-no-10))
- Solidity has a Matrix server: https://matrix.to/#/#ethereum_solidity:gitter.im

EDIT 2018: An active, public forum is https://ethresear.ch

Chat is at https://gitter.im/ethereum/research

https://ethereum-magicians.org is a forum [started by 2 members](https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/open-invitation-to-participate-in-a-fellowship/14) of the Ethereum Foundation.

---

From the [Ethereum blog post on communications September 2015](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/09/18/ethereum-comms-announcement):

> We will make an effort to de-emphasize Skype, and emphasize Gitter as
> a means of real-time communication for developers. Gitter has the
> advantages that (i) it’s easier to quickly jump in and participate,
> and (ii) chat rooms are public and visible to everyone by default.
> Currently, the primary active Gitter rooms are:
>
> https://gitter.im/ethereum/cpp-ethereum
>
> https://gitter.im/ethereum/pyethereum
>
> https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum
>
> https://gitter.im/ethereum/mist
>
> https://gitter.im/ethereum/web3.js

Gitter is still active and there are no indications of any Slack for Ethereum specifically.

https://gitter.im/ethereum is the place to see all the Ethereum channels and there have been additions than the ones initially listed above, for example governance, research, eips...

Answer (score 9):

Most core ethereum projects use public [gitter](https://gitter.im/orgs/ethereum/rooms) channels (gitter.im) as pointed out by Roman.

Answer (score 6):

Ethereum is a very de-centralized community and 
has several slack channels that you can ask to join
and freely discuss development of smart contracts:

```
ether.camp http://hack.ether.camp/
consensys ask for invite
slock.it  http://slock.it:3000/
```

are the most active today.

Comment: From what I recon, there is a dev Slack but it's not open (ethereum.slack.com is taken, at least).

From what I've seen the options you listed are too specific - I'm wondering why isn't there an open Slack for the entire Ethereum community yet.

Comment: most of the communication with the community is
on gitter channels

http://gitter.im/ethereum

Comment: Consensys Slack is not open for guests anymore, I hear.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open channel [ether-camp-friends.slack.com](http://ether-camp-friends.slack.com)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently in around a dozen slack teams which are related to Ethereum more or less. Sorted by popularity:

- [thedao](https://thedao.slack.com) (6409 members): public slack for [Slock.it](https://slock.it/) internet of decent-things and [The DAO](https://daohub.org/) decentralized venture capital.
- [colonycommunity](https://colonycommunity.slack.com) (2487 members): public slack for [Colony](https://colony.io/) 21st century companies project.
- [bitn](https://bitn.slack.com) (1004 members): public slack for [Bitnation](https://bitnation.co/) decentralized governance project.
- [ether-camp-friends](https://ether-camp-friends.slack.com) (978 members): public slack for the [ether.camp](http://www.ether.camp/) hackathon community and Ether Studio IDE.
- [dyffy](https://dyffy.slack.com) (869 members): public slack for the [Augur](https://www.augur.net/) prediction markets project.
- [cryptocommunity](https://cryptocommunity.slack.com) (732 members): A public slack for all crypto communities.
- [makerdao](https://makerdao.slack.com) (638 members): public slack for the [MakerDAO](https://makerdao.com/) issueing the Dai stablecoin on Ethereum.
- [coinality](https://coinality.slack.com) (414 members): public slack for the [Coinality](https://coinality.com/) digital currencies and blockchain job board.
- [synereonet](https://synereonet.slack.com) (290 members): public slack for the [Synereo](http://www.synereo.com/) decentralized social network.
- [ethchamps](https://ethchamps.slack.com) (190 members): public slack for the [EthChamps](http://www.ethchamps.org/) community volunteers (includes the main `#stackexchange` channel).
- [gnosis-pm](https://gnosis-pm.slack.com) (49 members): public slack for the [Gnosis](http://gnosis.pm/) decentralized prediction market.

Unfortunately, the slack desktop app does not allow more than 9 shortcuts for switching teams :-P

Answer (score 1):

[Ethereum NL](https://ethereumnl.herokuapp.com/) - public Dutch Slack community