# What is the most active Ethereum chatroom for devs? Slack? Telegram? IRC?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development

Where does most of the ethereum developers hang out? Slack? Telegram? IRC? I'm looking to join a chatroom where everyone can help others while developing.

Comment: I've been lurking around https://gitter.im/ethersphere/orange-lounge for quite a while now, its very active and the devs are extremely supportive

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/408/is-there-any-public-ethereum-communication-forums-or-slack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gitter is a great place to start. You can discuss specific technologies with devs on various projects:

- [Geth](https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum)
- [Truffle](https://gitter.im/ConsenSys/truffle)
- [Parity](https://gitter.im/paritytech/parity)
- [Vyper](https://gitter.im/ethereum/vyper)
- [Solidity](https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity)
- [web3.js](https://gitter.im/ethereum/web3.js)

To check out what the core devs are working on, check out [their Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/ethereum/AllCoreDevs).

For more long-winded questions and responses, check out [/r/ethdev](http://reddit.com/r/ethdev).

Twitter is also an excellent resource for direct interaction with people.

I have found that devs hang out on project-specific subreddits (0x, BAT, etc.), so asking a targeted question there should yield an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find telegram chat
https://t.me/dev_solidity